# Android Plugin add specific code to some method of source code

Tags: android, gradle, plugins

In the process of packaging Android app, if I want to insert some specific code to some specific method. How can I write the Android plugin. Is there any interface that I can override (such as get the method name, insert code to that method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Android Transform API](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api) to injecting custom class manipulations